# How to hide a label tag in jQuery that has a certain value for the "for" attribute?

Tags: jquery

I want to hide this label tag:

```
<label for="id_url">URL</label>
```

Only thing that distinguishes it from the other form elements is the value inside the for attribute. I don't have access to the form's html to add a class or id to it. So how can I hide it?

Answer (score 46):

Use the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).

```
$('label[for="id_url"]').hide();
```

If you need to use a separate variable that contains the target attribute value:

```
var target = 'id_url'; // or whatever
$('label[for="' + target + '"]').hide();
```

Comment: If you're using .net with dynamic controls you need this:   
    $('label[For$="EventTitle"]').hide();

Answer (score 13):

The attribute Equals selector will match exactly the value of any attribute.

```
$('label[for="id_url"]').hide()
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

You can also use other selectors (starts with, ends with, etc.) if you have many labels and/or can't necessarily search for a perfect match.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

**EDIT**: note that, from a performance standpoint, attribute-based selectors are fairly slow. If you have a lot of them, it could potentially cause a pretty noticeable slowdown in performance, especially in IE. If you find yourself needing to do this quite a bit, you may want to look at a larger architectural change (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('label[for="id_url"]').hide();
```